# IMAP, view email's labels, Python & Gmail

Tags: python, gmail, imap

How can I see what labels an email has?

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('myaccountxyz@gmail.com', mypassword)

mail.select("my-folder") # finds emails with this label
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, 'all')

for email_uid in data[0].split():
    result, data_single = mail.uid('fetch', email_uid, '(RFC822)')
    raw_email = data_single[0][1]
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
    sender = email_message['From']

    # get list of this email's labels
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this code myself, but according to [Google IMAP Extensions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions#access_to_gmail_labels_x-gm-labels), you should be able to just fetch the `X-GM-LABELS` item:

```
typ, dat = mail.uid('fetch', email_uid, 'X-GM-LABELS')
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! It's not a list of labels, but a single string that I can parse into a list. Also, the label that I used in the select in is not included.

Comment: `imaplib` doens't include a parser, unfortunately.  Any results you have to parse yourself.